# How to download map data of a specific country part?

Tags: openstreetmap, switzerland

For my project, I have to download the OpenStreetMap data of canton Zurich in Switzerland. I found osm files, but only for the whole country of Switzerland.

I already tried the export function of OpenStreetMap, but it did not work, because the area is to big.

I also tried http://export.hotosm.org, but the country is not supported.

Is there a way to download the map data for this specific part? The Switzerland package is quite big..

Comment: If you are using QGIS. You can get OSM data with **QuickOSM** plugin. See my answer here: [How to export OpenStreetMap data from QGIS for printing](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211861/how-to-export-openstreetmap-data-from-qgis-for-printing/211980#211980)

Comment: https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/metro/zurich_switzerland/ might be an alternative, though propapbly not covering the whole canton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is geofabrik.de

[This link](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/switzerland.html) will take you straight to the Switzerland download page. Sadly however this is for the whole country and as I write the downloadable zip file 469MB.  This is a good site to use forgetting OSM information as you can download different sizes of data from around the world...just not Switzerland at the moment sorry. There is also several file formats you can download.

Answer (score 4):

The OSM wiki lists various sources for [country and area extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). If these files are still too large for you then you can [split these maps into smaller geographical regions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats#Splitting_one_big_file_into_different_geographical_regions) with the help of various tools such as osmium, osmosis, osmconvert and so on. Furthermore you can also [filter for specific tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats#Filter_for_specific_tags) with osmosis, osmfilter or osmium.

Answer (score 2):

Zoom to your canton with http://overpass-turbo.eu/ and choose "export".

Comment: This query will surely time-out because the area is too big. It might be worth if only elements with certain tags are needed.

Comment: That's not really the case. I just tried it on a fast internet connection and didn't experience any issue at all. Just increase timeout and max element size: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/nDF - Download size 1 GB (uncompressed)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the download service of http://extract.bbbike.org/

where you should be able to select a bounding box manually, and then download raw OSM data in different file formats.